# gcc plugin c c++ find global nonstatic variables

Tags: c++, gcc, static, global-variables, gcc-plugins

i've been playing around with the gcc 4.6 plugin api.
For convenience i use a python wrapper/plugin for the api.

My goal ist to find the declarations of all variables with:

- global scope
- and not const
- and not static (means exported or visible)

in a compilation unit and emit a warning.
for eg:

```
int glob;              // exported
static int moduleGlob; // not exported
const int aModConst=42;
int f() {static int inner; return inner;}
```

should yield "glob"

"outside of functions/classes" and "const" is easy, but i can't get the "static" qualifier.

I am crawling the global namespace subtree and watch for VAR_DECL nodes not having the  const flag.

But how is the "static" keyword handled?
It does not seem to be one of the bitfield-flags. Also the "static predicate" on the node is misleading because it simply says that the variable goes in the static *storage* (which glob does - but also moduleGlob and inner). My questions rather is "will it be exported on a .so"

What about a "extern" declaration? How is that mapped in the AST?

Currently i try to do this in the *free_lang_data pass (is this too late?)

The only hint i have so far is this: When dumping the tree via the -fdump-tree-all switch is in the .tu dump there is an additional node whith the mangled name of the global variable (in the nonstatic case).

Any ideas how i could solve this?

Comment: How do you get access to global variables? I found your question while searching for that.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Working-with-declarations.html), it looks like you should use `DECL_THIS_STATIC` and `DECL_THIS_EXTERN`.